# Anonymize pandas name column with random 'nicknames'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, encryption

Let's say I have a pandas dataframe and a column 'name'. I want to anonymize the column and hide the identities. I can do something like,

```
df['nickname'] = 'P ' + pd.Series(pd.factorize(df['name'])[0] + 1).astype(str)
```

But it gives me this:

```
name       nickname  
frank miller   P 1       
john cena      P 2       
john cena      P 2       
rock           P 3
```

The above is an acceptable anonymization, but NOT what I need. Is there a way I can get the desired table below? Maybe a built-in python function or someone who has already implemented anything like this?

Desired Table (with random nicknames, but same output for the same input):

```
name       nickname  
frank miller   Tiko       
john cena      Bozo       
john cena      Bozo       
the rock       Hana
```

Comment: Where do you get this random nicknames?

Comment: if you want nickname that sound real, just download a list of name (https://www.randomlists.com/nicknames)  and just do a mapping table...

Comment: What about [this](http://listofrandomnames.com/)? You can generate a list of random names and use it as a conversion table.

Comment: @U10-Forward generate randomly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`Faker`](https://github.com/joke2k/faker) package for this which generates a dummy name for you.

**Installation**:

```
# pip
pip install Faker

# anaconda
conda install -c conda-forge faker
```

**Example**:

```
from faker import Faker
faker = Faker()
# seed the random generator to produce the same results
Faker.seed(4321)

dict_names = {name: faker.name() for name in df['name'].unique()}
df['nickname'] = df['name'].map(dict_names)
```

**Output**

```
           name     nickname
0  frank miller  Jason Brown
1     john cena  Jacob Stein
2     john cena  Jacob Stein
3          rock   Cody Brown
```

---

You can also initialize Faker with names from certain countries:

```
faker = Faker(['it_IT', 'de_DE', 'sv_SE'])

dict_names = {name: faker.name() for name in df['name'].unique()}
df['nickname'] = df['name'].map(dict_names)
```

**Output**

```
           name           nickname
0  frank miller    Nadeschda Finke
1     john cena      Marcus Warmer
2     john cena      Marcus Warmer
3          rock  Sophia Squarcione
```

Comment: this is so cool, thank you for introducing me to Faker! Will definitely be using this.

Comment: Thanks, I've been using it quite extensively the last couple of months, since we have to anonymize our data we get from the client. It can even generate city names, emails, streetnames etc. with `faker.city(), faker.email(), faker.address()` @ChrisA

Comment: @Erfan Is there a way that Faker returns same value for the same input each time as the first one? Like 'frank miller' giving 'Nadeschda Finke' everytime I run the Faker module?